# Tesseract OCR only numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract for iOS and I can't seem to figure out how to get it only to try and read numbers. I am using the newest english release downloaded from the tesseract website. Does anyone know how to do this?

These are the files I have:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a command-line execution, you'll need to also have `tessdata\configs\digits` file. If you're using the API, then call `SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789-.");`

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for my late response... just got back from my holiday. Anyway can you please tell me where I can find the digits file? The ones in my screenshot are the only ones that came with the download I got from the tesseract site. Thank you!

Comment: You can find it in [Tesseract SVN repository](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftessdata%2Fconfigs).

Comment: I have accepted your answer because I believe it is correct but do you mind explaining what to do next? I am new to this. I have done some research and according to another previous post (by you) you mentioned to look in usr\local\share\tessdata

Comment: But am I running the command SetVariable simply from the mac terminal within the digits folder? Also how do I incorporate the digits file into the files that I have shown in my screenshot? Thank you so much

Comment: Create a `configs` folder under `tessdata` and place the file there. If you execute from the command line, specify it as an option, such as: `tesseract imagename outputbase digits` (see [Tesseract Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ)). You use the `SetVariable` API if you want to programmatically call Tesseract, via Objective-C, for instance.