# OCR Tesseract set up only numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I am new to programming in general and have recently gotten into App development. I am using tesseract for iOS and I can't seem to figure out how to get it only read numbers.

There is an exact question posted by Alex G [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001338/tesseract-ocr-only-numbers) and I have the same files/problem as him. the answer apparently is

> Go to the tessdata\configs\digits file. If you're using the API, then
>   call  SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789-."); You use
>   the SetVariable API if you want to programmatically call Tesseract,
>   via Objective-C, for instance.

Except I still do not understand how to do this. Where is this command line? I am calling Tesseract from Xcode and not a command line. I also do not contain this tessdata\configs\digits file.

If somebody could please help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Ted
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [How To: Compile and Use Tesseract (3.01) on iOS (SDK 5)](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/) article, you would place the SetVariable statement after the Init call, as follows:

```
tesseract->Init([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "eng");
tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789-.");
```

Comment: Would be good to know how to generate `tessdata` for numbers only to reduce filesize.